# Android - Getting text for the selected item from ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I've spent several hours researching it, tried different approaches, but the closest I've got is getting the text for the first item in the list - not for the selected one.

This is my getView method:

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.sweetName = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.sweetName);
        holder.sweetPic = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.sweetPic);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    holder.sweetPic.setImageResource(sweetPicResource[position]);
    holder.sweetName.setText(sweetsNames[position]);


    return convertView;
}
```

And here is my onClickListener from the activity:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,int position, long arg3) {
                    String selectedSweet = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


                    TextView textView = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.sweetName);
                    String text = textView.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected item: " + text + " - " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
    );
```

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Before you post a question look around, there are thousands of questions like this one.

Comment: Yeah, as I've mentioned above, I've been researching it, looked on a number of similar questions and answers, but none worked for me.

Comment: TextView textView = (TextView) listView.findViewById(R.id.sweetName); --> TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sweetName);

Comment: @nbaroz when you have the answer always post it as an answer and not as a comment so that it may be closed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view,int position, long arg3) {
                    String selectedSweet = listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


                    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.sweetName);
                    String text = textView.getText().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Selected item: " + text + " - " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
    );
```